# Error with cross validation on a multilabel classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation, multilabel-classification

I'm using "multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier" and "cross_validation.StratifiedKFold". When I do cross validation on a multi-label problem, it´s fails.
Is it possible to perform cross-validation on a multilabel problem scikit-learn?

I think the problem is in the tuples of class label lists Eg ([1], [2], [2], [1], [1,2], [3], [1,2,3]. ..)

code in which I believe this error is as follows:

```
n_samples = X.shape[0]
Y_list = [value for value in Y.T]
print 'Y_list[0].shape:', Y_list[0].shape, 'len(Y_list):', len(Y_list)
cv = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(Y_list, 3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intend to solve multilabel task with scikit-learn, it's advised to first
transform your output to a label binary indicator using [MultilabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format).

Stratified k-fold doesn't support multilabel format as it's would require to balance the proportion of positive for each label. Instead, you can use a [K-folds](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold) or [shuffle split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit) cross validation strategy.

Comment: @Arnaud Joly What if I have multilabel classification and imbalanced data? so what should I do for making a balance training and testing set in each label? thanks:)

Comment: @sariii Use scikit-multilearn, which includes multi-label stratification (look up iterative stratification in the package)